# Why % is not allowed

Tags: java, special-characters

If i input passsword as `Admin$&%^` or `Admin$&^%` then my ajax call works but if i input it like this
`Admin$!%` or `Admin$!%^`. the ajax call throws following exception.....

Please help as i m not able to get the root cause for this issue

```
INFO: Character decoding failed. Parameter [txt_password] with value [Admin$!%] has been ignored. No
te that the name and value quoted here may be corrupted due to the failed decoding. Use debug level
logging to see the original, non-corrupted values.
java.io.CharConversionException: EOF
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.UDecoder.convert(UDecoder.java:80)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.UDecoder.convert(UDecoder.java:46)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.Parameters.urlDecode(Parameters.java:410)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.Parameters.processParameters(Parameters.java:370)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.Parameters.processParameters(Parameters.java:217)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.parseParameters(Request.java:2647)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.getParameter(Request.java:1106)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.getParameter(RequestFacade.java:355)
        at javax.servlet.ServletRequestWrapper.getParameter(ServletRequestWrapper.java:158)
```

While exploring i find that :

```
Special characters are not allowed inside the query string. They must be replaced by a "%" followed by the ASCII code in Hex. E.g., "~" is replaced by "%7E", "#" by "%23" and so on. Since blank is rather common, it can be replaced by either "%20" or "+" (the "+" character must be replaced by "%2B"). This replacement process is called URL-encoding, and the result is a URL-encoded query string.
```

So does that mean we cant use % as a value in input fields ?

Comment: Can you attempt this with debug level logging and provide those logs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally got the solution,

Before adding the parameters in query string i used encodeURIComponent function of javascript.
From [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeuri.asp)

```
The encodeURI() function is used to encode a URI.
This function encodes special characters, except: , / ? : @ & = + $ # (Use encodeURIComponent() to encode these characters).

Tip: Use the decodeURI() function to decode an encoded URI.
```

Answer (score 1):

You are attempting to URL-decode a string that has already been URL-decoded in a prior step.  That's your root cause.

The difference between your two sets of validated and invalidated strings is the '&' character.  Not sure exactly why the ones with an ampersand validate... possibly the parser stops before reaching the '%' because the '&' is viewed as a separator.